# select item in dictionary under array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, plist

my plist is like below:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>eye</key>
        <string>eye_man_blue</string>
        <key>lips</key>
        <string>lips_blue</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>eye</key>
        <string>eye_man</string>
        <key>lips</key>
        <string>lips</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

i need to select/read "eye_man_blue" forkey:eye atIndex:0.
this mean,if i do NSLog(@"%@.png",eyeDisplay);
it suppose to logging : eye_man_blue.png
i tried something like:

```
arrayItems=[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[arrayItems objectAtIndex:0], nil];
NSDictionary *itemdict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:itemArray forKey:@"eye"];
NSLog(@"%@",itemdict);
```

i get :

```
2011-12-21 11:00:30.749 project[358:f803] {
    eye =     (
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 1 array with 2 indexes, each index is a dictionary.

```
arrayItems=[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
NSString *myString = [[arrayItems objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"eye"];
NSLog (@"%@.png",myString);
```

Comment: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: No known instance method for selector 'forKey:'